# C# Windows 10 Toast Notifications

Tags: c#, windows, push-notification, toast

I'm trying to display a toast notification after a timer run out of time. 
The notification works on one of my PC's but the other one won't display it. I get no error when I'm debugging it. 
I also tried to set something in the Settings>Notifications but in the list of apps which are allowed/not allowed to display notifications I can't see my application.

This is my Notifications Class:

```
    class NewToastNotification
   {
      public NewToastNotification(string text)
      {
         string Toast = String.Format("<toast>"+
                                          "<visual>+" +
                                                "<binding template=\"ToastImageAndText04\">" +
                                                    "<text id = \"1\" >Toast Test </text>+" +
                                                    "<text id = \"2\" >{0}</text>+" +
                                                    "<text id = \"2\" >{1}</text>+" +
                                                "</binding>+" +
                                          "</visual>+" +
                                     "</toast>", text, DateTime.Now);

         var tileXml = new Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument();
         tileXml.LoadXml(Toast);
         var toast = new ToastNotification(tileXml);
         ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier("1").Show(toast);
      }
   }
```

Comment: I doubt the plus signs after your closing tags inside the strings are correct. Also are you sure having two text tags with the same Id is correct?

Comment: I think you are right and I changed it but it doesn't work either.

Comment: The PC on which the application works is using Windows 10 Pro, the other one Windows 10 Home is there maybe any difference concerning notifications?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
```

instead of

```
ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier("1").Show(toast);
```